# Some upgrades to my CopyFiles function C#

Tags: c#, file-io, progress-bar, messagebox

I managed to came up with function for my windows form program that will copy files from one directory to another and doesn't require exact path to directory as long as my program is in the correct directory (that part was really important).

I need to upgrade CopyFile function that I use in my program to make it do two more things:

1. Overwrite files in dir2 using files from dir1.
2. Let user know that function did it's job (either by attaching progess bar to it or something way simpler like windows messagebox with custom text on it).

So anyway thats my code:

```
      private static void CopyFiles(string source, string destiny, string pattern = "*.*")
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(destiny);

        if (!dir1.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException(source);
        else
        {
            if (!dir2.Exists)
                dir2.Create();

            FileInfo[] files = dir1.GetFiles(pattern);

            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                item.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dir2.FullName, item.Name));
            }
        }
    }

         static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CopyFiles(@".\FolderI\FolderII\", @".\FolderA\FolderB","a.*");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axsfwbc(v=vs.110).aspx) has an override that takes in a boolean stating whether or not to overwrite a file

```
item.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dir2.FullName, item.Name), True);
```

And change the return type of the method to a boolean which can say whether it was successful or not

```
private static bool CopyFiles(string source, string destiny, string pattern = "*.*")

... return True
```

You will need to update your code to return false if any errors (Hint: Try-Catch) or if anything else goes wrong

Comment: Someday, we will get through that "return boolean error code" pattern ;) Consider throwing an exception from the start (in the CopyFiles method).

Comment: Ok I looked at Try-Catch block syntax but I am not sure where to place it in my function code. I suspect it's suppose to go after foreach loop or maybe foreach loop should be included in Try part of the block?

Comment: @PatriceGahide - I was more thinking that this is a beginner programmer so it is best to start by learning the basics of returning values from a method, returning booleans is perfectly valid (i.e `TryParse` etc?). But yes, there are ways to return more improved information.

Comment: @Forc3ofWill - Try-Catches go around lines or blocks of code where you think it is possible that an error may occur but you don't expect it to happen (i.e to catch the unexpected)

Comment: @Sayse Ok I think I get it. So I have couple of options. I can include foreach in Try-Catch block for example and then if something goes wrong my function won't try to copy any more files. Or I can place  try
        {            
             item.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dir2.FullName, item.Name), true);
        }
 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Error!.", e);
        } before (after?) foreach loop and then it will still try to compy remaining files?

Comment: @Forc3ofWill - Yeah thats essentially correct, if you place it outside the foreach it will handle the exception as soon as it finds the first one, if you use a try catch inside of the foreach, it will try to carry on copying all the files, even if unable to do one of them. Note: It is considered bad practice to try to catch the base exception `Exception` as this may catch other things also that you didn't want it to, handling the exact exceptions is preferred. i.e `PathNotFoundException`

Comment: @Sayse I assume you ment DirectoryNotFoundException?

Comment: @Forc3ofWill - I just picked one at random that I could remember the name for, but yes if you look at the documentation to `CopyTo` it will show you what exceptions it can raise and `DNFE` is one of them

Comment: @Sayse I wasn't trying to be rude or anything like that. Just wanted to confirm because of my lack of experience. Thank you so much for your help! I've learned a lot.

Comment: @Forc3ofWill - No worries, I didn't think you were being rude. It actually shows you researched further which is always welcome :)

Comment: @Sayse Of course, I understood that was for simplicity. I just can't bear it anymore ;) And look, Forc3ofWill seems to get away from the dark side, isn't that great? Best of luck with your learning.